# Inserting element and extend into numpy array based on position

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have an np.array X of size 1253 with some number (for demonstration value is all 1)

Now i want to insert 0s into this array based on position.

```
array([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
     11,   12,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,
     35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,   45,
     46,   47,   48,   49,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,
     74,   75,   76,   77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,
     85,   86,  108,  109,  110,  111,  112,  113,  114,  115,  116,
    117,  118,  119,  120,  121,  122,  123,  149,  150,  151,  152,
    153,  154,  155,  156,  157,  158,  159,  160,  161,  189,  190,
    191,  192,  193,  194,  195,  196,  197,  198,  199,  229,  230,
    231,  232,  233,  234,  235,  236,  237,  269,  270,  271,  272,
    273,  274,  275,  309,  310,  311,  312,  313,  314,  348,  349,
    350,  351,  352,  388,  389,  390,  391,  427,  428,  429,  467,
    468,  506, 1014, 1052, 1053, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1129, 1130, 1131,
   1132, 1168, 1169, 1170, 1171, 1172, 1206, 1207, 1208, 1209, 1210,
   1211, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1283, 1284, 1285,
   1286, 1287, 1288, 1289, 1290, 1291, 1321, 1322, 1323, 1324, 1325,
   1326, 1327, 1328, 1329, 1330, 1331, 1359, 1360, 1361, 1362, 1363,
   1364, 1365, 1366, 1367, 1368, 1369, 1370, 1371, 1397, 1398, 1399,
   1400, 1401, 1402, 1403, 1404, 1405, 1406, 1407, 1408, 1409, 1410,
   1411, 1412, 1434, 1435, 1436, 1437, 1438, 1439, 1440, 1441, 1442,
   1443, 1444, 1445, 1446, 1447, 1448, 1449, 1450, 1451, 1452, 1453,
   1471, 1472, 1473, 1474, 1475, 1476, 1477, 1478, 1479, 1480, 1481,
   1482, 1483, 1484, 1485, 1486, 1487, 1488, 1489, 1490, 1491, 1492,
   1493, 1494, 1508, 1509, 1510, 1511, 1512, 1513, 1514, 1515, 1516,
   1517, 1518, 1519, 1520], dtype=int64)
```

You see, what i want is to extend the size of my original X to size 1521, with 1s in original position but 0's in these specified position. So new array will be size 1521, zeroes in all these position.

How can i do that?

Comment: (Note: the answer describes using a list of indices for this, but an array of indices works too.)

Comment: You question will be much easier to understand with a minimal example (4/5 indices **maximum**), a reproducible array of the input, **and the matching expected output**.